# Javascript: How to find difference for two number arrays

Tags: javascript

I need to create a new array made up of unique elements from two separate arrays.

I have converted both arrays into a single array and then converted this into an object to check the frequency of the elements. If the value of an object property is 1 (making it a unique property), I want to return it to an array (minus the value). Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Edits: Moved result outside for loop. Expected output should be [4]

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var finalArr = [];
  var countObj = {};
  var newArr = [...arr1, ...arr2];
  for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (!countObj[newArr[i]]) countObj[newArr[i]] = 0;
    ++countObj[newArr[i]];
  }
  for (var key in countObj) {
    if (countObj[key] === 1) {
      finalArr.push(key);
    }
  } return finalArr;
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can add the output that you are expecting from `diffArray` call at the end

Comment: It should be `finalArr.push(key)` instead of `key.push(finalArr)`. And `return finalArr` from outside the `for` loop

Comment: Use a `Map`, not an object. That won't convert your keys from integers to strings.

Comment: If your arrays are both sorted and duplicate-free, there's a much simpler solution using a merge algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to find the difference between `arr1` and `arr2`, and returns that difference (if any) as a new array of items (that are distinct in either array).

There are a number of ways this can be achieved. One approach is as follows:

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {

  const result = [];
  const combination = [...arr1, ...arr2];
  
  /* Obtain set of unique values from each array */
  const set1 = new Set(arr1);
  const set2 = new Set(arr2);

  for(const item of combination) {

    /* Iterate combined array, adding values to result that aren't
    present in both arrays (ie exist in one or the other, "difference") */
    if(!(set1.has(item) && set2.has(item))) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), " should be [4]");
console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3, 5]), " should be [8]");
console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3, 5, 9]), " should be [8, 9]");
console.log(diffArray([1, 2], [1, 2]), " should be []");
```